# Apple rejected my app due to Other "Business Model Issues"

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

On my iTunnes Connect I have 4 applications that I developed for my clients(Financial apps for trading) and when I tried to upload it, but I've been rejected by Apple(before 2018 year it wasn't a problem):

**Guideline 3.2.1 - Business - Other Business Model Issues - Acceptable.
The seller and company names associated with your app do not reflect the financial institute name “XXXX Bank Ltd.” in the app or its metadata, as required by Guideline 3.2.1(viii) of the App Store Review Guidelines.
Specifically, your app must be submitted by XXXX Bank Ltd. Developer account to be in compliance with this guideline.
Next Steps
Your app must be published under a seller name and company name that reflects the Discount Bank Ltd. name. If you have developed this app on behalf of a client, please advise your client to add you to the development team of their Apple Developer account.**

As I understand the problem that I am developing third party apps for my clients and this is not acceptable by apple. Do I need to create 4 apple id users and certificates for each client and then to upload it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We are facing exactly the same problem. Has never been a problem until now. Are there any news in your case? Have you found a solution?

Comment: @vitali, have you solved this problem

Comment: @Anurag Bhakuni You need to create a new account for the client and upload application under this name otherwise Apple won't approve it.

Comment: i am also facing the same issue for taxation app (Tax Advisor) is there any way the my client app will be accepted on my appstore or i need to buy separate account and submit it?

Answer (score 1):

Like @Vitali said - You need to create a new account for the client and upload application under this name otherwise Apple won't approve it.

But if you already have this account, you have to check at the bottom of the page this option. After you have to put your business's ID. Check the IMG please. More information here... https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204401 I hope this helps you.

[image: Section Price][image: Bottom page custom B2B]
[image]

PD: Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, each of your clients banks is supposed to create its own Apple developer account and submit its app itself. See [§4.2.6 of the App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#minimum-functionality):

> **4.2.6** Apps created from a commercialized template or app generation service will be rejected unless they are submitted directly by the provider of the app’s content. These services should not submit apps on behalf of their clients and should offer tools that let their clients create customized, innovative apps that provide unique customer experiences. Another acceptable option for template providers is to create a single binary to host all client content in an aggregated or “picker” model, for example as a restaurant finder app with separate customized entries or pages for each client restaurant, or as an event app with separate entries for each client event.

If the bank hires you to manage its developer account and submission process, that is probably sufficiently direct to comply with the guideline, especially if you are careful to use contact information that belongs to the bank (like the bank's mailing address and an email address that uses the bank's domain name).